# django-lfs "No module named appconf"

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a problem after installing django-lfs

> 'compress' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading compressor.templatetags.compress: No module named appconf

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    
Django Version: 1.3.1
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
'compress' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading compressor.templatetags.compress: No module named appconf
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py in load, line 1054
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
```

http://dpaste.com/1653897/

how to fix it??

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried installing [django-appconf](http://django-appconf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#installation)?